# how to put forms in a separate file Angular 4

Tags: angular

I'm trying to organize my project, and it using the form group makes the component look messy. I want to know if there is a way to put the form builder in a different class and call it inside my main component.
I'm using Reactive Form.
I'm trying to avoid all of that declarations
Thank you

```
constructor(private http: Http, private _filterService: FiltreAdvancedSearchService) {
this.loading = true;

this._filterService.getAllData().subscribe(res => {
  this.Recherche = res;
  this.loading = false;
  this.status = 304;

},   err => {
  this.status = err.status;
  console.log(this.status)
});
this.SearchForm = new FormGroup({
  start_date: new FormControl('', [Validators.required ]),
  end_date: new FormControl('', [Validators.required ]),
  n_doc: new FormControl('', [ Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$') ]),
  pw: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$') ]),
  li: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$') ]),
  fac: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('^[0-9]+$') ]),
  cont: new FormControl('', [Validators.pattern('/^[a-zA-Z]$/') ]),
  type: new FormControl(this.types),
  cat: new FormControl(this.categories),
  immat: new FormControl(),
  ser: new FormControl(''),
  mod: new FormControl(''),
  en: new FormControl(this.energies),
  client_num: new FormControl(),
  client_nom: new FormControl(),
  reg: new FormControl(),

});
```

}

Comment: Post your code so that it's easy to identify how can your code be optimized

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's possible to put the form builder outside the ngOnInit() function for example. You can do it like this:

```
ngOnInit(){
blablabla ...
this.buildform();
}

buildForm() {
        this.form = this.fb.group({
            Id: [{ value: '', disabled: true }, Validators.required],
            Insertions: [{ value: '' }, Validators.required],
            IdForm: [{ value: '', disabled: !this.is_edit }, Validators.required],
            price: ['', Validators.required]
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Create an injectable service class with static functions like this. Add more functions for separate forms.

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators} from "@angular/forms";
@Injectable()
export class FormHelper {

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) {}

  buildForm1(entityName: string): boolean {
    return this.fb.group({
      'firstName': [null, [Validators.required]],
      'secondName': [null, [Validators.minLength(10), Validators.maxLength(2000)]]
    });
  }
}
```